# Make nested Zod object partial at only a specific level

Tags: zod

I'm currently working on an Express app and using Zod to validate an incoming request.
One "problem" I'm often facing is that the schema used to validate a body for a creation route for instance  `POST /contracts` is often used again in a `PATCH /contracts/:contractId` request except now all keys are optional.

I know Zod provide a `deepPartial` method but this not really what I want sometimes my schema contains 3 or 4 nested objects and I only want one level to be `partial`, moreover in Zod 3.22.4 `deepPartial` is deprecated.

What I'm currently doing is:

```js
const contractBodySchema = z.object({
    name: z.string(),
    nestedObject1: z.object({
        value1: z.number // this value should never be optional
    })
});

const contractCreationSchema = z.object({
    body: contractBodySchema
});

const contractUpdateSchema = z.object({
    body: contractBodySchema.partial()
});
```

It works fine but I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do this and maybe avoid creating the `contractBodySchema` and recreating multiple `z.object({ body: ... })`.

**EDIT**

Another problem I encountered is adding nested properties to an existing schema.

Let's say I have this schema

```js
const mySchema = z.object({
    value1: z.object({
        value2: z.object({
            value3: z.string()
        })
    })
})
```

How do I add `value4: z.number()` inside the `value2` Zod object?

Cheers.